# Проблема с Retrofit

Tags: android, retrofit

Хочу получить данные из запроса,через библиотеку retrofit.В методе onRespone() по всем туториалам параметры List и Response,а у меня Call> и я не могу теперь его передать в обычный лист,для заполнения данных.
Вот мой код фрагмента:

```
public class FeaturedFragment extends Fragment {
    public static final String ROOT_URL = "https://api.vid.me";
    private List <Video> videos;
    RecyclerView recList;

    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_featured, container, false);
        recList = (RecyclerView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.cardList);
        recList.setHasFixedSize(true);
        LinearLayoutManager llm = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
        llm.setOrientation(LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
        recList.setLayoutManager(llm);
        return rootView;
    }

    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        try {
            getVideos();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void getVideos() throws IOException {

        Retrofit retrofitAdapter = new Retrofit.Builder()

                .baseUrl(ROOT_URL)
                .build();
        VideoApi videoApi = retrofitAdapter.create(VideoApi.class);

videoApi.getFeaturedVideo(new Callback<List<Video>>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(Call<List<Video>> call, Response<List<Video>> response) {
        videos = call;//ОШИБКА ЗДЕСЬ!Нужен java.util.List найден retrofit2.Call

    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(Call<List<Video>> call, Throwable t) {

    }
});
    }
}
```

videoApi class:

```
public interface VideoApi {

    @GET("/videos/fatured")
    Call<Video> getFeaturedVideo(Callback<List<Video>> response);
}
```

Video class:

```
  public class Video {
        private  String url,title,description;
        private  int score;
        public String getUrl() {
            return url;
        }

        public void setUrl(String url) {
            this.url = url;
        }

        public String getTitle() {
            return title;
        }

        public void setTitle(String title) {
            this.title = title;
        }

        public String getDescription() {
            return description;
        }

        public void setDescription(String description) {
            this.description = description;
        }

        public int getScore() {
            return score;
        }

        public void setScore(int score) {
            this.score = score;
        }


    }
```

Comment: Ошибка у вас из-за то что пытаетесь скастовать List<Video> к Call<List<Video>>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Забирать нужно отсюда `response.body();`

```
 @Override
    public void onResponse(Call<List<Video>> call, Response<List<Video>> response) {
        videos = response.body();

    }
```

`response.body()` - возвращает ваш сериализованнй объект

Comment: можно,пожалуйста,поподробней?

Comment: Обновил ответ, смотрите

Comment: спасибо,заработало